# Divider between two specific table columns?

Tags: tables, columns, line, vertical

I have a table that logically looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|    METACOLUMN A   |    METACOLUMN B   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
-----------------------------------------
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 |
-----------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is place a vertical divider between METACOLUMN A and METACOLUMN B *without* placing dividers between 1, 2, 3, and 4 creating something like this:

```
  METACOLUMN A  |  METACOLUMN B
 --------------------------------
 1   2   3   4  | 1   2   3   4  
 A1  A2  A3  A4 | B1  B2  B3  B4
```

Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume your current code contains the following directive:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

or maybe

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
```

Just change that directive to

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc|cccc}
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc|cccc} % note: just 1 instance of "|"
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Meta A} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Meta B}\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & B1 & B2 & B3 & B4 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!